# Change the background color of a td element depending on his numeric value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table structure where I want to change the background color depending on the value.

For example

```
<td class="tg-yw42">0</td>
<td class="tg-yw43">1</td>
<td class="tg-yw44">0</td>
```

So if value is => 0 apply green background otherwise leave it as it is.

Hope this make sense

Comment: How are you generating the table?

Comment: CSS cannot select content.  You would need to use some sort of script.  Unless you could add a class based on content when the table is generated (see previous comment).

Comment: @SamuelAsor I've written the html  for the table. All I need is a little js/jquery script to change the background but I've very little experience with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the table rows and apply `css` based on the criteria of table cell `text == 0`.

```js
$("table td").map(function () {
  if (parseInt($(this).text()) === 0) $(this).css("background-color", "green")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg-yw42">0</td>
  <td class="tg-yw43">1</td>
  <td class="tg-yw44">0</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**ES6 way:**

```
$("table td").map((i, el) => parseInt($(el).text()) === 0 ? $(el).css("background-color", "green") : "")
```

Comment: OP's case is where the `value = 0`, and not `>=0`

Comment: Oops.. got confused with `=> 0 ` in OP's question. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 1):

Since you put jquery in the tags, here is jQuery solution. You can use `$.each()` to iterate through all `<td>`'s, check the value with `text()` and apply a class accordingly.

```js
$('td').each(function() {
var $this = $(this)
  if ($this.text() == 0 ) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw42">0</td>

    <td class="tg-yw43">1</td>

    <td class="tg-yw44">0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick response and I cannot go through all of the td tags as there are some in there which I dont need to change therefore I need to be more explicit and provide the actual css class

Comment: So... you want to use a set of specific classes to check the values and apply a styling class to only those in that specific list?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the jQuery selector's `.text()` to get the content of any selected element.

So for instance

```
$('td.tg-yw42').text()
```

will return 0 (the content of that specified element).

Now you can combine that with `.each()`, which will execute the specified function for every element that the jQuery selector has found.

So this code:

```
$('td').each(function() {
  var nr = $(this).text();
  /* other code */
});
```

will go through all of your `td` elements and set the variable nr to its content.
Then all you have to do is using conditions to set its background or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery.

First get all the `tds`:
`tds = $(document).getElementsByTagName("td")`

Then iterate through the array:

```
for( td of tds){
  assignColor(td);
}

 // The function giving the background color
function assignColor($element){
    switch ($element.text()){
      case '0':
        element..css("background-color", "yellow");
      default:
        break
    }
 }
```